# PHP form validation to do alert if no error

Tags: php

I have the following form validation.

```
<?php 

    $error_occured = 0;
    $error_name = "";
    $error_email = "";
    $error_contact = "";
    $error_comments = "";

    if(isset($_POST["tx_name"])) {

            if(($tx_name == "") || (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$tx_name))) {
                    $error_occured = 1;
                    $error_name = "Please enter a valid name";
                }

            if(($tx_email == "") || (!filter_var($tx_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
                    $error_occured = 1;
                    $error_email = "Please enter a valid email";
                }

            if(($tx_contact == "") || !(is_numeric($tx_contact))) {
                    $error_occured = 1;
                    $error_contact = "Please enter a valid contact number";
                }

            if($tx_comments == "") {
                    $error_occured = 1;
                    $error_comments = "Please enter your message";
                }


        }

    if(isset($_POST["tx_name"]) && $error_occured = 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Hi!');</script>";
        }

?>
```

The validation works fine and if there is no error, its supposed to do an alert. However, when I submit the form with no error, I do not see the alert message. How do I fix this?

Comment: In last condition, use `$error_occured == 0` . Using boolean is also not a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you Yash Mehta, I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<?php 

$error_occured = 0;
$error_name = "";
$error_email = "";
$error_contact = "";
$error_comments = "";

if(isset($_POST["tx_name"])) {

        if(($tx_name == "") || (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$tx_name))) {
                $error_occured = 1;
                $error_name = "Please enter a valid name";
            }

        if(($tx_email == "") || (!filter_var($tx_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
                $error_occured = 1;
                $error_email = "Please enter a valid email";
            }

        if(($tx_contact == "") || !(is_numeric($tx_contact))) {
                $error_occured = 1;
                $error_contact = "Please enter a valid contact number";
            }

        if($tx_comments == "") {
                $error_occured = 1;
                $error_comments = "Please enter your message";
            }

     if($error_occured != 1) {
        echo "<script>alert('Hi!');</script>";
      }
 }



?>
```

Comment: This works, thank you! But I have a question, why it doesn't work when I put `if($error_occured = 0)` instead of `($error_occured != 1)` ?

Comment: You need `==`. That;s how you check if is equal. In my example I check if is different because you have 1/0. If there are more errors like 2, 3, 8 .. etc will be better to be `==`

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.